# SpringBoot actuator always execute test email

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a springboot application, and the actuator performs many requests on my mail server.

I created an example in my [github](https://github.com/felipeflores/TestSpringBootMail) to demonstrate this.

increase the property **eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds** is not a solution, I would like it to never test in email or database (in my example I do not have a database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

Just set a property management.health.mail.enabled=false